# ASP.NET MVC Role Authorization based on Site/URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm creating a single web application that I will be deploying to different sites (e.g., red.domain.com, blue.domain.com, etc). I want different roles to have access to the different sites (e.g, the "red" role will have access to red.domain.com).

Currently I am using controller-wide authentication (e.g., [Authorize(Roles = "red")]). When I deploy my application to a site, I have to change the role on each controller (e.g. from "red" to "blue"), which seems ridiculous.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can streamline this? Maybe a setting I can create on the IIS site itself that automatically applies the correct role?

Thanks much.

Comment: do those different deployment share same database?

Comment: Then what if you just use same Role name?

Comment: Ha - I'm sorry. Same database for authentication. (Different database for the data.) But it might just be easiest to use separate authentication databases. Thank you. Definitely an option.

Answer (score 1):

Could be good place for dependency injection. A library like [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) allows you to define type mappings in web.config (I'm assuming you have one web.config for each site)

So, if you have `RedController` and `BlueController`, that both implement a common interface `IColourfulController` it would look something like this:

```
<!-- red web.config-->
 <DefaultInstance
      PluginType="IColourfulController, [assembly name]"
      PluggedType="RedController,  [assembly name]" />

<!-- blue web.config-->
 <DefaultInstance
      PluginType="IColourfulController, [assembly name]"
      PluggedType="BlueController,  [assembly name]" />

// when you need the controller
IColourfulController controller = 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IColourfulController>();
```

Both sites can use the same code for getting the controller, but the web.config says whether it will be blue or red.